# 2 Background colours with border radius on first section

Tags: html, css, background

i want to be able to create something like this in the photo with CSS and HTML, i did so using tis line of code `background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(32, 34, 47) 35%, rgb(29, 31, 41) 35%);`

But with this, I am unable to create a border-radius kind of effect as shown in the photo, can someone please guide me on how I can do this? current I have applied that CSS code to the `body` tag.

[Image showing 2 background colors with bottom border-radius effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aguYq.png)

Comment: thats a fundemantal issue you having here. Besides the fact that you didnt provided any relevant code (especially HTML). To Border radius will be applied to an element liek a div class not to a backgroudn image. As the Background image would be insde a div or other eleemnt, you should be able to style it just normally. If you want a backgroudn image with border-radius, wrap the background-image inside a divwith a negative z-index.

Comment: there is literally no HTML code since I'm applying it directly to the body tag. the css is 
body {background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(32, 34, 47) 35%, rgb(29, 31, 41) 35%);
}

What i can't figure out is how to apply it to the full body of the document, as im using bootstrap container as my first very DIV after the Body tag

Comment: like I said, fundemental issue. You cant not apply a broder radius on backgroudn image as the background image is no HTML element, its a css/style element. As such you need to wrap it inside a div and style the div with a border radius. YOu can use a wrapper (div to contain the background image), style the wrapper with a border radius and push it into the very background with a negative z-index value.

Comment: ahhhh i see, gotcha ill try that out and let you know thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To eloborate what I already told you in the comments. You cant use a broder rdaius on a stylign elemnt only on a HTMl element. As such you have to use a pseudo-div and push it to the background with a negative z-index. The div is a HTML elemnt and as such can also be styled that way.

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

#background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 60%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: blue;
}

#content {
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="background">
  <div id="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey, that was absolutely brilliant, just one thing using position fixed made it un-scrollable so I fixed it by using position: absolute. thank you so much tho guess I have a long way to go before truly understanding the fundamentals of some basic things in CSS

Comment: also adding a z-index makes elements not being able to interact with for example button, removing it still works perfectly fine for the background, was there any particular reason for adding it in ?

Comment: Z-Index can be descriped as layers. the higher the z-index the more it will eb on top of every thing else. Especially if you want to use it a background for your body, you wouldnt want to interact with it anyways. so you push it layer-wise down. everything down so it it will act as a background for the body.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:
in the HTML,create a div element and nest an other div inside it, the first nested div will be your upper border, the second one will have the text (or any content):

```
<div class=container>
  <div></div>
  <div>text here</div>
</div
```

for the CSS, you need to apply some basic styling (background, size, border) and make sure that the border-radius are the same in all of the div element, and that the first nested div has a height >= border-radius :

```
.container {
  background-color:grey;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  border-radius:6px;
}

.container :first-child{
  width:100%;
  height:6px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(32, 34, 47) 35%, rgb(29, 31, 41) 35%);
  border-radius:6px 6px 0 0;
}

.container :last-child{
  width:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 6px);
  border-radius:0 0 6px 6px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```